# Confused by lifetime of Box<Trait> in struct

Tags: rust, lifetime, trait-objects

```
struct Wrap<'a> {
    pub data: Option<&'a i32>,
}

pub trait Boxable {
    fn get_data(&self) -> Option<&i32>;
}

impl<'a> Boxable for Wrap<'a> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> Option<&i32> {
        self.data
    }
}

struct ContTrait {
    pub vbox: Box<Boxable>,
}

struct ContWrap<'a> {
    pub vbox: Box<Wrap<'a>>,
}

fn main() {
    let x1 = 15;

    let bt = Box::new(Wrap { data: Some(&x1) });
    // let mut c = ContTrait { vbox: Box::new(Wrap {data : Some(&x1)}) };
    let mut c2 = ContWrap {
        vbox: Box::new(Wrap { data: Some(&x1) }),
    };
}
```

I can't justify why only the commented line can't be compiled and thinks `x1`'s lifetime is not long enough. It seems `c2` is equivalent to it, except the `Box` is for the `Wrap` struct directly. `bt` just removes one layer of struct. I can't figure out what makes `ContTrait` behave so differently.

Here's the error message when uncommenting the `ContTrait` line:

```
error[E0597]: `x1` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:63
   |
27 |     let mut c = ContTrait { vbox: Box::new(Wrap {data : Some(&x1)}) };
   |                                                               ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
31 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=4e6e28ab1804cece6dc29109a385dd65)

Comment: `Box<Trait>` is equivalent to `Box<Trait + 'static>`. If you want some other lifetime, you need to be explicit and use `Box<Trait + 'a>`.

Comment: (Not sure whether this qualifies as a duplicate, but the answer covers the important points to note here.)

Comment: Based on your error messages, you are still using Rust 2015. You are encouraged to [switch to Rust 2018](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html), which provides a better error message here.